# How to add a computed observable to a mapped view model?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'd like to simply add a computed observable to a object that is mapped.  I'd like to avoid adding a parent view model.  I've tried using the mapped options create but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$.getJSON(apiUrl, function (data) {

         var mappingOptions = {

          // overriding the default creation / initialization code
          create: function (options) {

          ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);

           // setup the computed binding
           this.FullNameComputed= ko.computed(function () {
                   return this.FirstName() + this.LastName();
                  }, this);               
            }        
          };

          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, self.Users);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a computed observable after performing mapping:

```
$.getJSON(apiUrl, function (data) {

  var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

  vm.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
    return vm.FirstName() + ' ' + vm.LastName();
  });
});
```